# Jquery: calculation in each row of a table showing same result in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have a table with dynamical functionality to add rows. That means user can add any number of results.

The rows have a select field and one text input field. When users select a value from select field, text input field is populated with result given by Ajax call multiplied with another input field on form.

I am getting the result but problem is that each text input in each row is populated with same result.

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<table>
<tr class="items2"><td><select id="Account" value="1">ajax text</td><td><input  class "amount"/></td></tr>
<tr class="items2"><td><select id="Account-1" value="2">ajax text</td><td><input  class "amount"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
            $("select[id*='Account']").change(function(){
            subjectId=$(this).val();
            console.log(subjectId);
            var sale=$("#id_sale").val();
                        console.log(sale);

            request_url = '{% url "taxrate" pk=0 %}'.replace('0', subjectId);
            console.log( "request_url = " + request_url);
            $.ajax({
                            url: request_url,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: 'json',
                        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                        $.each(data, function(n, obj){



                        $("tr.items2").each(function () {
                        $('.amount',this).val( ((sale*obj.fields.rate)/100).toFixed(2));


                        })

                        })
                        })

            });

        </script>
```

What mistake is in my code? I am just a newbie at front end.

Image: In image you can see that text input is showing 140 in both boxes. But it should show amount only if i select another row select item. Amount should be calculated as per ajax value passed for the row.
[image]

JSfiddle without ajax part:

https://jsfiddle.net/tL86dsmc/

```js
$("select[id*='Account']").change(function(){
   subjectId=$(this).val();

   var sale=$("#id_sale").val();

      var tax_rate = ((sale * .10)).toFixed(2);

      $(".amount").val(tax_rate);
      
       
   
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="id_sale" value=100>
<table>
  <tr class="items2">
    <td>
      <select id="Account-1" value="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="1">tax @18%</option>
        <option value="2">Tax @ 17%</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="amount-2" class="amount">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="items2">
    <td>
      <select id="Account-2" value="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="1">tax @18%</option>
        <option value="2">Tax @ 17%</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="amount-2" class="amount">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What kind of element is `<iselect>`? Should it have a closing tag? Why there are multiple elements with the same `id`?

Comment: @Teemu changed it to <select>, that was a typo, as did not copy paste whole code but typed. Id is also changed, it will increase with every new dynamic row.

Comment: `data` is single object or array?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN data is an array but contains single line.

Comment: No solution yet!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it using class

```
<script>
$(".items2").change(function(){
subjectId=$(this).val();
console.log(subjectId);
var sale=$("#id_sale").val();
console.log(sale);

request_url = '{% url "taxrate" pk=0 %}'.replace('0', subjectId);
console.log( "request_url = " + request_url);
$.ajax({
    url: request_url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        $("tr.items2").each(function () {
            $(this).find('.amount').val(((sale*obj.fields.rate)/100).toFixed(2));
        })
    })

});
</script>
```

Comment: Its not working. Console is not printing subjectId, subject id value is row value but it should have value of select.

Comment: You just assign a class to your select inside your tr, and use that class in the first line $(".selectClass").change(function(){//code goes in here});

Comment: Or you can try this selector:
$(".items2 select").change(function(){
//your code goes here
});

Comment: Tried doing that, its functioning same as my code. Still if i add another row, the input text get populated.

Comment: I have edited lines inside your done function after the ajax call, have tried them?

Comment: that gives error ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Answer (score 0):

you're getting the same result because of the [attribute-contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) as every time the user adds row the script select the id with value=1, and its value gets inserted into the input text field. You can try changing the id selection in script with the class.

Comment: Did not get it. I am using class for every function. Can you please give an example that would be great!!! Thank you for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
 $(this).parent().next().find('input.amount')
.val(((sale * data[0].fields.rate) / 100).toFixed(2));
```

Remove this part

```
 $.each(data, function(n, obj) {
      $("tr.items2").each(function() {
        $('.amount', this).val(((sale * obj.fields.rate) / 100).toFixed(2));
      })
    })
```

> Issue

```
$('.amount',this).
```

will access every input element regardless select control that is changed.

Comment: If i remove the lines you said, console gives error. **ReferenceError: obj is not defined** .

Comment: Please add response

Comment: ReferenceError: obj is not defined
<anonymous>
createinvoice:864
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()
jquery-1.12.3.js:3232
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()
jquery-1.12.3.js:3362
done()
jquery-1.12.3.js:9852
.send/callback()

Comment: Raw data: [{"model": "invoice.ledgermodel", "pk": 431, "fields": {"rate": 14.0}}]

Comment: Json data: 0{model: "invoice.ledgermodel", pk: 431, fields: {rate: 14}}

Comment: `<script>
   $("select[id*='Account']").change(function(){
   subjectId=$(this).val();
   console.log(subjectId);
   var sale=$("#id_sale").val();
      console.log(sale);

   request_url = '{% url "taxrate" pk=0 %}'.replace('0', subjectId);
   console.log( "request_url = " + request_url);
   $.ajax({
       url: request_url,
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'json',
      }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      
       $(this).parent().next().find('input.amount').val(((sale * data[0].fields.rate) / 100).toFixed(2));
   })
   });
   
  </script>`

Comment: Its not calculating.